# Search issues in my starred repositories only ? [Github]

Tags: github, github-api

I want to get a list of issues with particular label (e.g. `help-wanted` label) and those issues must refer only to my starred repositories

Is it possible to do with standart Github search qualifiers or single API method?

Something like `type:issue state:open label:help-wanted refer:starred-repo`

I haven't found such prefixes in a [standart search](https://github.com/search) and such options in [advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced).

Also I haven't find single API method to solve this problem. I found only following methods:

- `GET /users/{username}/starred` ([List repositories starred by a
  user](https://docs.github.com/rest/activity/starring?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-repositories-starred-by-a-user))
- `GET /search/issues?q=repo:USERNAME/REPOSITORY+label:help-wanted` ([Search
  issues and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-issues-and-pull-requests), [Constructing a search query](https://docs.github.com/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#constructing-a-search-query))

But using them looks not optimal. E.g. if I have 300 starred repos I need to make 300 API requests to get issues from those repos.

Is there any other ways? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you might be right unfortunately. I (or rather, GPT-4) made a command-line tool and web interface to do exactly what you said: https://github.com/llllvvuu/contributor-tools/tree/main/github_issues

It takes about a minute to run while I have 288 starred repos and limiting to 100 issues per repo.

My plan is to just pull it every day or every week.